# Deleting records with condition when creating a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I join using keys.
In the second table, there are several records for users with the same foreign key. And I want to check if in any of these records, if there is a user, there is no key when the group is created.

[image]

```
SELECT table1.question_id, table2.user_id  
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.question_id = table2.question_id
GROUP BY question_id, 
        CASE WHEN table2.user_id != '100' 
            THEN table1.question_id 
            ELSE null 
        END
```

my simple query.

add condition in where and this not worked.

Comment: And what's a group on this context?

Comment: group by question_id, this picture, query return null

Comment: You want to skip the group entirely if there's a user with id 100?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the groups using the `NOT EXISTS` operator

```
SELECT table1.question_id, table2.user_id  
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.question_id = table2.question_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT t2.user_id
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.question_id = table1.question_id
    AND t2.user_id = 100
)
GROUP BY table1.question_id
```